# Wordpress ajax запрос 400

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

В плагине отправляю запрос следующего вида

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {data : jsonString},
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.plugin-debug').html(response);
    }
});
```

Получаю `load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.3.2:4 POST http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

html содержимое

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" id="upload-form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload_image">
    <div><h3>Загрузите 3 изображения</h3><input id="upload-image" name="image-field" type="button" value="Выбрать изрбражения"></input></div> 
</form>
```

php скрипт

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload_image', 'upload_image' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_image', 'upload_image' ); 

function upload_image() {
    echo $_POST['data'];
    die();
}
```

В data я передаю следующие данные

```
var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').map(); //Данный берутся с media modal
let images = [] //Массив для ссылок
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    images.push(attachment[i].toJSON().url); //Достаем ссылку в виде строки
}
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(images); //Ну и тут просто массив строк
```

В log файлах тоже ничего нет.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eI27.png. Укажите что передается в data? https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLZso.png

Comment: В data передается массив конвертированный в JSON. Массив содержит строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ 400 (есть разница с 404, я исправил заголовок), означает, что запрос неправильно сформирован. Посылаемые данные ни при чём, у вас отсутствует action в вызове.

Надо так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        data : jsonString,
        action: 'upload_image',
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.plugin-debug').html(response);
    }
});
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Comment: Не понимаю, а что ```<input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload_image">``` не будет работать? Просто у меня есть другие формы и в них я использую данный код, чтобы как раз таки добавить action и все отлично работает.

Comment: Это так же не решает проблему. Возможно я не подключил какие-то скрипты/модули, которые необходимы для работы wp-ajax? Хотя, на сколько я знаю, ajax из под админки должен работать по дефолту и больше ничего не надо.

Comment: aciton, указанный в input, используется только php. В формировании ajax - запроса он не принимает никакого участия - посмотрите поля в запроса во вкладке Network.

Comment: Где у вас код, описанный в разделе `php скрипт`?

Comment: С ```action``` я понял, убрал ```input``` и добавил ```action``` в сам запрос. Как я и говорил, ничего не изменилось. В самом скрипте пока ничего нет, я просто пытаюсь сделать запрос с простым ответом.

Comment: В каком файле находится код с add_action?

Comment: В том же где и скрипт и Html код. Все в одном файле

Comment: вот ссылка на код всего плагина https://pastebin.com/ad61re8z

Comment: Я поправил ответ. action должна быть внутри data, т.е. попасть в $_POST. Сейчас всё работает, проверил.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я только что сам понял это.